# Why i am not able to connect to SQL Server via VSCode?

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server

OS: Ubuntu 19.04

I have installed SQL Server using tutorial by Microsoft, and after running command `systemctl stop mssql-server` i can see it's running.

But when i'm trying to connect to this instance via VSCode (using extension SQL Server for VSCode), it says "Connection" and nothing happening. Server name: localhost

Comment: systemctl stop mssql-server will STOP your server, yeah?

Comment: yes, aswell as systemctl stop mssql-server will start

Comment: can you connect natively with `sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourPassword>'`

Comment: @Narzard the problem is: i can't install sqlcmd, got error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: msodbcsql17 (< 17.4.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: do this `sudo apt-get install libodbc1 unixodbc msodbcsql mssql-tools unixodbc-dev -y`

Comment: @Narzard yeah i already tried, got error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 msodbcsql : Depends: libcurl3 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Check the post [unable-to-install-msodbcsql17-on-ubuntu-18-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129309/unable-to-install-msodbcsql17-on-ubuntu-18-04). It might be helpful.